# How I can revert email confirmation in ASP.NET membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am using ASP.NET membership in my project and when ever user created I manually confirm his email address by this code:

```
string code = await  UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id.ToString());
await ConfirmEmail(user.Id.ToString(), code);
```

By this, users doesn't need to verify his login by using confirmation link sent to his email address , by the way this is project requirement.

Now I want to revert this process by C# code. I want to unconfirmed his email address, so how I can achieve this requirement?

Comment: What actual change is made in the data when a user is confirmed?  Seems like you just need to update the data to modify that value again.

Comment: i want to use built in aspnet membership methods if available

Answer (score 0):

So, there is a "built in method", but it's not exposed on the `UserManager` that you can access.

The UserManager has an internal property `Store` which inherits from [`IUserEmailStore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613269.aspx) which has the methods used by the UserManager when you ask it to confirm an email address ([`ConfirmEmailAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151625.aspx) calls `IUserEmailStore.SetEmailConfirmed`) and also when you check to see if an email is confirmed.

The [`SetEmailConfirmed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt173654.aspx) method takes a Boolean parameter `confirmed` which can therefore be set to `true` or `false`.